# (window).height() for iPad screens

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, height

I have a popup on my site.  After the popup opens, I resize it to take up most of the screen:

```
jQuery( window ).resize(function() {
    var windowHeight = jQuery(window).height();
    jQuery('#BookingFrame').css('height', windowHeight * 0.9 | 0);
});
```

Problem: On iPad, the window resizes past the viewport and the bottom half of the popup disappears. There is literally no way to complete the form on an iPad.

I've seen a lot of explanations on here about the "why" but I have not been able to find a workable solution. Any changes suggested in these forums results in breaking another part of the page or site on other devices.

I'm thinking I need to identify the device ($device==iPad) and then change the windowHeight to windowHeight * 0.5 or something similar. Is this the best solution? or is there something simpler?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what browsers you need to support you could use [vh units](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css_units.asp) instead of px/rem/% so you eliminate the need for js to resize the popup.

Comment: that is fine and works on all screens BUT I load the popup with a URL and when the URL loads, the page is longer than screen and ONLY on iPad, does it them resize the height (so the initial vh unit is overridden on iPad)

Comment: I'm a little confused by your follow up. Is the popup an iframe? Is there some js styling the element inline and overriding your css?

Comment: There is an iframe inside the popup which is loaded after click. There is no JS at all anymore.